# Get name of file in a variable using grep

Tags: shell, unix, grep, save, filenames

In Unix box, in a particular path only one file(one at a time only) having name `xyz_timestamp.input` is present.

Example: `xyz_182456.input` (hhmmss)

Now I need to get that file name in a variable, where I only do know file will contain `xyz_*.input` but timestamp is not fixed. I am trying it for shell scripting

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `basename` to do that.

```sh
$ FNAME=$(basename xyz_*.input)
$ echo $FNAME
xyz_182456.input
```